# is there a clue to determine whether colorspace conversion via cvtcolor is needed

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, imread, opencv3.2

I used imread to upload an image from the disk (I thought BGR is the default output of cv::imread ). Then, I used cvtcolor to convert the image from BGR (the default of OpenCV) to RGBA (the default of CUDA).

I thought I should make sure that the image was converted correctly so I displayed ( and saved) the converted image. However, the image colors were distorted & looked Bluish when I used imshow & imwrite. For debug purposes, I tried to revert the conversion to the image debugImage & surprisingly it was displayed correctly.

```
  cv::Mat image;
  image = cv::imread("input_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open file: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
  }
  int type1 = image.type(); //16 --> CV_8UC3
  cv::namedWindow("image window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
  cv::imshow("image window", image);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::destroyWindow("image window");

  cv::Mat imageRGBA1(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC4);
  cv::cvtColor(image, imageRGBA1, CV_BGR2RGBA); // BGR2RGBA DIDNOT WORKED!!
  int type2 = imageRGBA1.type(); // 24 --> CV_8UC4
  cv::namedWindow("imageRGBA1 window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("imageRGBA1 window", imageRGBA1); // BLUISH IMAGE
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::destroyWindow("imageRGBA1 window");

  cv::Mat debugImage(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC4);
  cv::cvtColor(imageRGBA1, debugImage, CV_RGBA2BGR);
  int debugtype = debugImage.type(); // 24 --> CV_8UC4
  cv::namedWindow("debugImage window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
  cv::imshow("debugImage window", debugImage); // CORRECT IMAGE
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::destroyWindow("debugImage window");
```

When I assume the image obtained from imread was the RGB image the conversion works:

```
cv::Mat image;
  image = cv::imread("input_image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if (image.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open file: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
  }
  int type1 = image.type(); //16 --> CV_8UC3
  cv::namedWindow("image window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
  cv::imshow("image window", image);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::destroyWindow("image window");

  cv::Mat imageRGBA1(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC4);
  cv::cvtColor(image, imageRGBA1, CV_RGB2RGBA); // CV_RGB2RGBA WORKED!!
  int type2 = imageRGBA1.type(); // 24 --> CV_8UC4
  cv::namedWindow("imageRGBA1 window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("imageRGBA1 window", imageRGBA1); // CORRECT IMAGE
  cv::waitKey(0);
  cv::destroyWindow("imageRGBA1 window");
```

what am I missing?

Comment: "When I assume the image obtained from imread was RGB" -- Why would you assume that, when the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) clearly states that "In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order."? And just like `imread` works with BGR order, same applies to `imwrite` and `imshow`. Therefore, if you swap the blue and red channels and display the result, it should not be much of a suprise that what was red becomes blue and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that imread expected BGR image.